# How to output to S-Video on Windows XP in single-monitor mode (clone display)?

Tags: windows-xp, display, thinkpad, s-video

I am using an IBM ThinkPad T30 running Windows XP. It is connected to a TV system via S-Video output.

Windows is currently set up in multi-monitor mode with monitor 2 being output to S-Video. However, since there is no preview monitor, I can't interact with anything I drag to monitor 2 as I can't see it.

I would rather have the system set up so that there is only one monitor and the output is cloned to the laptop display and S-Video. This allows me to see what I'm doing on the TV system. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading the specs for this right, you are using the "ATI RADEON 7500 Mobility video chipset". You'll need to make sure you have the latest [drivers](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-42358.html). If that doesn't include the "Catalyst Control Center" (ATI driver utility) you'll need to use windows to manage the desktop mirror.

1. Right click on the desktop and go to properties.
2. Click the settings tab.
3. You should see two screens.
4. Make sure that neither one has “Extend my Windows desktop onto this monitor” checked.

If you only have one screen on the settings tab, and you don't have the ATI driver utility. Either IBM has their own utility to do this, or you'll have to go to ATI (now AMD) and dig through the driver archives until you find a package that has the driver utility. That one should give you the option to clone screens onto the S-video port.

As a final thing, you might be able to access the Utility from the Advanced button on the settings tab. There may be a tab for ATI in there.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

On most laptops with an external display jack, you can use a keyboard shortcut to toggle between the built-in display, the external display, cloned display, or extended display (e.g., both displays side-by-side).  The key for switching display modes on PC laptops is usually either two bulging rectangles (usually one is only an outline and the other is filled in), or a bulging rectangle with two vertical lines (one on each side).

Judging from a few pictures I found online, it looks like your key combination is Fn+F7.  Fn is located in the lower left corner of the keyboard, and F7 is located in the row of F-keys just above your number row.

View the image below at full size to see the keys more clearly.

[image: Thinkpad T30]